# Is there a minimum elapsed time required before a classified document can become declassified in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, confidentiality

Is there a minimum elapsed time required before a classified document can become declassified in the U.S.? I am wondering if any classified document can become unclassified at any time or not. I am thinking there's a minimum elapsed time, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. A classification decision can be reversed by an original classification authority at any time, and the “declassify by” date on a classified document can be arbitrarily close. For instance, a military order might be set for automatic declassification once the operation is complete.

Comment: Most material is automatically declassified after 25 years (with some exceptions for highly sensitive information) if it doesn’t have a set “declassify by”date. Almost everything someone might need to know about the US classification system is covered in [EO 13526](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2010/01/05/E9-31418/classified-national-security-information)

Comment: Also, as evidenced by Trump most recently, the President can declassify something at any time they please.